# Make two socket connections talk to each other

Tags: node.js, sockets, ember.js, express

Here is the scenario...

I am working on an app I had an idea for, I'm building it in ember with an express backend. I am using the `express-ws` so I can run the `ws` websocket package inside express better. I was not able to get just ws to work with express.

My app will have two people connecting to two different url's that are socket connections, so that they can send and receive information to the server without the other getting it. At least that's the way I've come up in my mind to do it.

What I want is when one user does an interaction over the socket, for that socket to send a message to the other socket to perform an action and send it's information to the user connected on it.

I hope that makes sense. With express-ws here is what I have done so far which works at a basic level.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('middleware');
  req.testing = 'testing';
  return next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('browser connected');
  res.send('welcome to the api browser');
});

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  console.log('socket connected');
  var object = {
    message: 'welcome to the socket api',
    time: Date.now().toString()
  }
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(object));
});

app.listen(1337);
```

I haven't made the other connection yet but for the time being it will be the same, but when the user on one connection sends a certain message to their socket, I want that socket to perform something and then pass some data to the other socket so it can send some information to it's user.

Comment: What you want to do is store references to each open channel and then listen to their `onmessage` event

Answer (score 1):

This might give you an idea of how to store the references for later use:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

// array to hold the connections
var openChannels = [];

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('middleware');
  req.testing = 'testing';
  return next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('browser connected');
  res.send('welcome to the api browser');
});

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  console.log('socket connected');

  // store connection for later reference
  openChannels.push(ws);

  // @todo: remove from array on disconnect

  // set broadcast callback
  ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
    openChannels.forEach(function(index, item) {
      if (item !== ws) { // make sure we're not sending to ourselves
        item.send(msg);
      }
    });
  };

  var object = {
    message: 'welcome to the socket api',
    time: Date.now().toString()
  }
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(object));
});

app.listen(1337);
```

Comment: I think I am getting this, could I also set each `app.ws` equal to a variable name and send messages the same way or does it have to be what is returned from the anonymous function that I send messages to?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do? If you want to pass messages from one user to another or from a user to the server, you'd have to somehow identify them up front (think of a login). You could then bind the socket to the user identity which is what i think you're trying to do!?

Comment: I think the answer you gave will be what I need, the idea is I really just need a way for socket 1 to know it needs to send the next step to it's user once socket 2 has completed it's step. It's sort of like each person connects on their own secure socket and completes steps that initiate other steps for the other person